# Можно ли сделать скриншот синхронно?

Tags: javascript, html2canvas

Пытаюсь сделать скриншот элемента:

```
let imgData = ''
console.log('до imgData', imgData)
html2canvas(screen.current).then(function (canvas) {
    imgData = canvas.toDataURL();
    console.log('внутри imgData', imgData)
    });
console.log('после imgData', imgData)
```

Но проблема в том, что скриншот делается асинхронно, а мне надо синхронно. Как это сделать?

UPD:

Глобально ситуация выглядит так:
Я отслеживаю закрытие вкладки. Когда пользователь закрывает вкладку - у меня запускает определенная функция и там есть фунционал скриншота элементов.
Если пользователь нажмет "НЕТ", то все отработает и скриншоты будут, но если пользователь нажмет "Да", то выполняются ровно те функции, которые без async/await.
А так как html2canvas сохраняет скриншоты асинхронно, то он не выполняется...

Comment: Если что-то асинхронное, синхронным оно не станет...

Comment: Может есть решение синхронное?

Comment: уже классика.......см. дубликат.... можно этот ответ: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1476674/191482  в самом низу

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, с какой стати это дубликат? Он не спрашивает, как асинхронный код синхронно вызвать, а спрашивает, как сделать синхронно. Может там другое апи есть?

Comment: @Qwertiy используя async / await можно спокойно сделать то, что ТС хочет сделать..... а сделать он хочет следующее: исполнить вначале функцию, а потом сделать другой код...... так что вполне себе дубликат

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, я считаю, что он спрашивает о существовании синхронного апи для скриншота.

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский, async/await не помогает, в моем случае надо выполнить только синхронно код. Т.к. async/await выполняется уже тогда, когда уже поздно..

Comment: @Алексей исправляйте ваш случай так, чтобы он умел работать с асинхронным кодом

Comment: @Алексей можете пояснить что значит *"async/await не помогает"*? что что подразумеваете под *"только синхронно"*? почему только так а не иначе? и самое главное, что значит ""async/await выполняется уже тогда, когда уже поздно"" ? для чего поздно?

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский обновил

Comment: Тогда, наверное, было бы лучше озаглавить вопрос чем-то вроде «Можно ли сделать скриншот в момент закрытия вкладки?»